# jQuery not working on one PC and working on another

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery + PHP code that works on one PC but not on the other.

**Non-working:**

```
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/hrscripts/sortable.js"></script>
  <link href="/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="/javascripts/select2.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#select_employee").select2();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<?php
  $allemp=$this->AllEmployees;
  echo "<form method='post' action='' id='employeesselection'>";
  echo "<select name='select_employee' id='select_employee'>";
  echo "<option value=''>Select an employee...</option>";

  foreach($allemp as $row) {
    $selected = ($row['Id'] == $_POST['select_employee'])?'selected="selected"':'';
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['Etunimi'].' - '. $row['Sukunimi'].'</option>';
  }
  echo "</select>";
```

**Working:**

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <link href="css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="select2.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#select_employee").select2();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<?php
  include "db.php";
  $employees=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asiakas");

  echo "<form method='post' action='' id='employeesselection'><select name='select_employee' id='select_employee'>";

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($employees)) {
    $selected = ($row['Id'] == $_POST['select_employee'])?'selected="selected"':'';
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['Etunimi'].' - '. $row['Sukunimi'].'</option>';
  }
  echo "</select>
```

It is almost the same code. I cant figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: If you test locally, the `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>` won't work.

Comment: @RobertLee, Yes I am sure that the file is in the right place. I have phpStorm and it tells when a file cannot be found .

Answer (score 0):

The http:// is missing:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can also try to remove the leading slash on the script path: <link href="/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/javascripts/select2.js"></script> There is a difference between /javascripts and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Check both results on the same browser, and also make sure that all page scripts have been loaded, 
you can do that on chrome from **"f12 -> resources -> scripts"**